# Add options to Bootstrap Modal Show

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the following code to show a modal on page load, how can I add Bootstrap options to the code below?

**For example backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false**

```
jQuery(function($){

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show') 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 14):

According to the [Bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript), you can specify options like so:

```
jQuery(function($){

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal({
            show: true,
            keyboard: false,
            backdrop: 'static'
        }) 
    });

});
```